# How to return an array translation in I18n zh-CN file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am trying to provide an array input in `zh-CN` for 'date.order' but did not get it. Here is the story:

```
date_order = I18n.translate(:'date.order', :locale => :en, :default => [])
date_order = ["year", "month", "day"]
```

A translation is needed for

```
date_order_cn =  I18n.translate(:'date.order', :locale => :zh-CN, :default => [])
```

Here are what I tried in `zh-CN.yml`

```
date:
    order: 
      year : '年'
      month : "月"
      day : "日"
```

with the error:

```
"translation missing: zh-CN.date.order"
```

What is the right way to provide array translation for `date.order`?

Answer (score 0):

Your zh-CN.yml file should be like below,

```
zh-CN:
  date:
    order:
      year : '年'
      month : "月"
      day : "日"
```

And the o/p like below,

```
I18n.translate('date.order', :locale => 'zh-CN', :default => [])
#=> {:year=>"年", :month=>"月", :day=>"日"}
```